# Parsing multiple XML documents in Java

Tags: java, xml

Being inexperienced in Java and the manipulation of XML i am stuck on an issue.

Consider this XML snippet:

```
<Rule Name="Assistant">
<RuleVersions>
    <Adjustments>
        <Adjustment Type="Bonus" BonusRateHourlyRate="10"></Adjustment>
    </Adjustments>
    <RuleVersion EffectiveDate="01/1/1753" ExpirationDate="01/1/3000">
        <Triggers>
            <SimpleValue Value="2204"/>
            <SimpleValue Value="2206"/>
        </Triggers>
    </RuleVersion>
</RuleVersions>
```

Ultimately what i need to achieve is to extract the Rule Name and then every attribute associated with it to create an output of this:

```
Assistant Type Bonus
Assistant BonusRateHourlyRate 10
Assistant EffectiveDate 01/1/1753
Assistant ExpirationDate 01/1/3000
Assistant SimpleValue 2204
Assistant SimpleValue 2206
```

As i need to pass hundreds of XML files, all with different structures, i was aiming to create some reusable code that could just iterate through each document and create this output, irrespective of its format. The one thing that is consistent is that the Name (column 1 of the output) will always be in the format of Name="xxx".

The following code gets me close on the above sample XML, but has a few issues:

1. It requires hardcoded xpaths so it is not reusable across different documents
2. it fails to get the second SimpleValue 2206

   ```
       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Output\\XML\\Test.xml"));
       DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
       Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
       XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       String TestCase = "";
       String name = "Rule/@Name";
       NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(name).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

       NodeList Type = (NodeList) xPath.compile("Rule/RuleVersions/Adjustments/Adjustment/@Type").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList BonusRateHourlyRate = (NodeList) xPath.compile("Rule/RuleVersions/Adjustments/Adjustment/@BonusRateHourlyRate").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList EffectiveDate = (NodeList) xPath.compile("Rule/RuleVersions/RuleVersion/@EffectiveDate").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList ExpirationDate = (NodeList) xPath.compile("Rule/RuleVersions/RuleVersion/@ExpirationDate").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList SimpleValue = (NodeList) xPath.compile("Rule/RuleVersions/RuleVersion/Triggers/SimpleValue/@Value").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

       //Build the test cases file
       for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
           TestCase = TestCase + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + " Type " + Type.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n";
           TestCase = TestCase + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + " BonusRateHourlyRate " + BonusRateHourlyRate.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n";
           TestCase = TestCase + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + " EffectiveDate " + EffectiveDate.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n";
           TestCase = TestCase + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + " ExpirationDate " + ExpirationDate.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n";
           TestCase = TestCase + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + " SimpleValue " + SimpleValue.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n";

       }
       System.out.println(TestCase);
   ```

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction or give me some sample code that could help me achieve the result i am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this updated answer now I made this to read all the attributes and their values. you need to download sax2r2.jar file you will get at [this](http://sourceforge.net) website.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class NewClass extends DefaultHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
            String adjustment,ruleVersion,simpleValue;

            DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qname, Attributes attributes) {
                    if(attributes.getLength()>0)
                    {
                        int items = attributes.getLength();
                        System.out.println("Qualified Name:"+qname);
                        for(int i=0;i<items;i++)
                            System.out.println(attributes.getQName(i)+":"+attributes.getValue(i));
                    }

                }
            };
            saxParser.parse("e:\\abc.xml", defaultHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have this working just as i need it using this code which also strips out a few extra pieces i didn't require, and adds the name at the start of each line:

```
try {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler() {
            String ruleName = null;
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qname, Attributes attributes) {

                if (attributes.getLength() > 0) {
                    int items = attributes.getLength();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
                        if ((qname.toString().equals("Header")) || (qname.toString().equals("Response"))) {
                            //Dont print out the XML headers
                        } else {
                            if (attributes.getQName(i).equals("Name")) {
                                ruleName = attributes.getValue(i);
                            } else {
                                //Don't reset the string;
                            }
                            System.out.println(ruleName+":"+qname + ":" + attributes.getQName(i) + ":" + attributes.getValue(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        saxParser.parse(
                "Test.xml", defaultHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be writing low-level Java code for a problem like this. It's much better done in XSLT or XQuery.

Your example output isn't achievable in a completely generic way because you are handling different elements differently, for example with Adjustment/@Type you output the attribute name, but with SimpleValue/@Value you output the element name. Let's suppose that's an oversight. Then this XSLT rule would give you what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="Rule//@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::Rule/@Name, ' ', name(), ' ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

That has to beat writing reams of Java code.